# showing almost equal function are actually equal

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to show that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on $[a, b]$ and if $f=g$ a.e. on $[a, b]$, then, in fact, $f=g$ on $[a, b]$. Also would a similar assertion be true if $[a, b]$ was replaced by a general measurable set $E$ ?

**Some thoughts towards the proof**

1. Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions, so for all open sets $O$ and $P$ in $f$ and $g$'s ranges respectfully the sets $f^{-1}\left(O\right) $ and $g^{-1}\left(P\right) $ are open.
2. Also since $f=g$ a.e. on $[a, b]$ I am guessing here implies their domains and ranges are equal almost everywhere(or except in the set with measure zero).
   $$m(f^{-1}\left(O\right)  - g^{-1}\left(P\right)) = 0$$

I am not so sure if i can think of clear strategy to pursue here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Also i would be great full you could point out any other general assertions which if established would prove two functions are the same under any domain or range specification conditions.

Cheers.

Comment: You can use continuity to show that if $f$ and $g$ take different values at $c$, then they take different values at every point of some (small) nhood of $c$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The set $\{x\mid f(x)\neq g(x)\}$ is open (it's $(f-g)^{—1}(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})$), and of measure $0$. It's necessarily empty, otherwise it would contain an open interval.

Comment: It's also worth thinking about what this argument says when you take complements: if a set has full (Lebesgue) measure (i.e. its complement has measure zero) then it is dense, and two continuous functions which agree on a dense set must agree everywhere.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo Just a quick question why did you exclude the set containing zero from R

Comment: @Hardy Because $f(x)-g(x)=0$ means that $f$ and $g$ agree on $x$. We look at where they don't.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you very much for the other pointer.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker but ofcourse, that make perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ vanishes a.e. on $[a,b],$ there exists a measurable set $X$ s.t. $m(X)=0$ and $f=0$ on $[a,b]\setminus X.$
But $m(X)=0$ implies that $X$ has empty interior, (because any non empty open set has positive measure), or equivalently its complement is everywhere dense.

Now, from $f=0$ on $[a,b]\setminus X$ and $[a,b]\setminus X$ dense in $[a,b],$ we conclude that the *continuous* function $f$ vanishes everywhere on $[a,b].$

P.S. The same argument works for continuous functions on any Euclidean space.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge I have corrected my wrong terminology.

Answer (score 2):

A subset of an interval of full measure is dense in that interval. If two functions agree on a dense set, they are equal everywhere.